# Regex pattern not working properly on matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
ben[0]='zc5u5';
icb[0]='M';
bild[0]='b1_413134.jpg';
ort[0]='Köln';kmm[0]=0.00074758603074103;alt[0]='18';
jti[0]=413134;
upd[0]='u41313486729.js';
jon[0]=0;
jco[0]=0;
jch[0]=0;
ben[1]='Oukg5';
icb[1]='M';
bild[1]='mannse.jpg';
jti[1]=412425;
upd[1]='u41242570092.js';
jon[1]=0;
jco[1]=0;
jch[1]=0;
ben[2]='Tester356';
icb[2]='M';
bild[2]='b1_247967.jpg';
```

I want to get the names from`ben[]`, for example the first one would be `zc5u5`.

I do currently have this code:

```
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(ben\\[\\d+\\]=').+?'");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

            LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

            // Loop through and find all matches and store them into the List
            while(matcher.find()) {
                list.add(matcher.group());
            }
```

Unfortunately the pattern does match the whole line, instead of just the value, e.g. `zc5u5`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you want to capture? `ben` and `zc5u5` or just one of them?

Comment: Just ``zc5u5``. My pattern does indeed work (kinda), unfortunately it captures the whole line, that's not what I need.

Comment: Nevermind, @Elliot's answered pretty much got it, I just did it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two groups if you want to capture the index and the value, and I would add support for optional white-space around the assignment (`\\s*`). Something like,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ben\\[(\\d+)\\]\\s*=\\s*'(.+)';");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.printf("index %s = %s%n", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
ben\b.+'(.*?)'
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT8jC1/1)**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ben\\b.*'(.*?)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.printf(matcher.group(1));
}
```